# SRX240 - unable to ping Default DG from router

Tags: juniper

Just want to ask how come i couldn't get a connection form srx directly to my PC.

My configuration  goes like this:

```
set interface ge-0/0/5 unit 0 family inet address 10.10.1.1/24
commit
```

When i statically assign `10.10.1.2/24` DG `10.10.1.1` i cant ping the DG.

Based on my understanding with cisco it should work.

What i want to happen is just get the host to ping the DG i set on SRX.

Answer (score 0):

an SRX is a firewall, you need a permit host-inbound-traffic stanza on the zone or the interface inside the zone that permits ICMP echoes against the firewall.